# Calling server-side function from HTML on click (Classic ASP)

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to use my if else statement inside my `Function Save()`  but I cannot make it works? After click on the img button I want to verify if `mycheckBox_A` is checked. By the way **I am using classic ASP**

```
    <img src="blah" onclick="<%Save()%>"/>     

    <%
    Function Save()    
      If mycheckBox_A.checked Then    
         'mycheckBox_A is checked    
      Else    
         'mycheckBox_B is checked 
      End If
   End Function
    %>
```

Comment: mixing server-side code with client-side events, eh?

Comment: @konrad: now i am really confused. why did you remove the *classic asp* from the question and tag both? the Op might have been using *classic asp* !

Comment: I am using classic asp

Comment: you will have to use javascript for that.

Comment: call the form's **submit** method from ur Script

Comment: @abhitalks On the second thought removing this tag as it was in title as well was stupid, true. I've just seen many times when people added both ASP.NET and ASP-classic tags and they were talking about .NET.

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to do after clicking on that image? Do you want to do something with your generated HTML or maybe you want to do something in your database for example? Only the name of the function `Save()` makes me think that you might want to do something on server side.

Comment: Yes i want to do something on server

Comment: @user3138076 Added a simple example of how to do what your asking without any client side script.

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` attribute is not for calling server-side functions. You can assign JavaScript to this one, but not VB function. Think if you really need server-side code here that's possible that all you need in this exact place could be done with JavaScript.

**EDIT:**

If you need to do something on the server, you have to use AJAX to send only data you want to the server or submit the form with [submit button](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) or JavaScript call to [`submit()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp) method. After submitting date you have to process it in your server-side function. Check [this short tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/aspTutorial/aspFormsPost.php) on processing submitted with both `POST` and `GET` methods.

Comment: you removed the *classic asp* from title as well as tag? why do you think the Op is using asp.net and not classic asp when the Op specified that in the original question?

Comment: @abhitalks On the second thought removing this tag as it was in title as well was stupid, true. I've just seen many times when people added both ASP.NET and ASP-classic tags and they were talking about .NET. This general mistake let me to removing the "classic" tag and treating the question as question about .NET version and answering it as it's about ASP.NET.

Comment: please update the answer to remove the onserverclick and runat server part. so that i may reverse the downvote.

Comment: @Lankymart ^^ So I'll remove those comments of mine too. :D

Answer (score 1):

According to [how to call a ASP function in the onclick event](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?61106-how-to-call-a-ASP-function-in-the-onclick-event):

> ASP functions execute only on the server side, while the onclick event
>   executes only on the client side. You are trying to mix the two in an
>   impossible way.
>
> The problem is that the function calculate() does not exist on the
>   client-side. The browser cannot see it.
>
> You will need to use JavaScript (or another client-side technology) if
>   you want to have this type of functionality.

This also applies to your `Save()` function.

Comment: Then how can I do this

Answer (score 0):

You can't use onclick like this. Your only option is to have the button be either a submit button, or a link, then handle it on postback (if you need to do it server-side) or to write it in javascript if it can be done client-side.

Using postback to handle server logic is quite simple and basically how it works in modern ASP. You could have the submit button be in a form which has an integer, showing what you want to do, then handle this at the top of the page. That way, you can postback to the same page, handling different kinds of logic depending on what button was pressed, etc.

Should be noted that this makes for pretty ugly code, but then again, it's classic ASP.NET, it will look ugly no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use any client script here at all

```vb
<%
'Have you POST to this page?
If Len(Request.Form) > 0 Then Call Save()

Sub Save()
  Dim a_check, i_item, i_items
  a_check = Split(Request.Form("checkbox") & "", ",")
  If IsArray(a_check) Then
    i_items = UBound(a_check, 1)
    For i_item = 0 To i_items
      'Could store this and output it later on but is just a quick example
      Response.Write a_check(i_item) & " is checked"
    Next
  End If
End Sub
%>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- make the page POST to itself -->
    <form method="POST" action="">
      <! -- your other fields etc

      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="A" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="B" />

      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Quick example nothing special untested.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JQuery post method and pass your variables to classic asp page.